# bold exponent in siunitx

Tags: siunitx, bold

I have a large table of numbers generated from a script, and I use `siunitx` to format the output nicely. I would like to highlight the important part of the numbers, which is the exponent, in bold, so that it stands out (the number itself is not as important as the order of magnitude, yet scientific notation makes the exponent less visible, as superscript).

I'm using these settings

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
         exponent-product = \cdot,
         round-mode = figures,
         round-precision = 1}

\num{2.12e-14}
```

[image]

but I would prefer the visual equivalent of

```
$2\cdot 10^{\mathbf{-14}}$
```

*Edit:* For a real-world example, see the two large tables in the Appendix of this [pdf document](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.00798v1.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX, it may be easier to just create a dedicated Lua function and set up an associated TeX "wrapper macro" rather than to try to hack the `\num` macro of the `siunitx` package. In the example below, the wrapper macro is called `\mynum`, and its syntax is set up to be mimic the behavior of the `\num` macro.

The only assumption that's made about about the numbers to be formatted is that their exponent part is non-empty, i.e., that the numbers contain an `e<nn>` substring, where `<nn>` is a positive or negative integer. With this setup, a number such as `e1234` is a valid input for `\mynum` (and for `\num` too).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{exponent-product = \cdot,
         round-mode       = places}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function formatnum ( prec, num )
if string.find ( num , "[%d%.]+[eE]" ) then
   mant = string.format( "%."..prec.."f".."\\cdot", string.match ( num, "[%-%+]?[%d%.]+" ) )
else 
   mant = ""
end
expo = string.gsub ( num, ".-[eE]([%-%+]?)(%d+)", "10^{%1\\mathbf{%2}}" )
return ( tex.sprint( "$"..mant..expo.."$" ))
end
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\mynum[2]{\directlua{ formatnum ( \luastring{#1}, \luastring{#2})}}

\begin{document}
\def\NumA{2.12e-14}
\def\NumB{12.34e56}
\def\NumC{e1234}

\num[round-precision=0]{\NumA}

\mynum{0}{\NumA}

\medskip
\num[round-precision=2]{\NumB}

\mynum{2}{\NumB}

\medskip
\num[round-precision=4]{\NumC}

\mynum{4}{\NumC}
\end{document}
```

*Addendum*: If you wanted to highlight the exponent in red instead of using **bold-facing**, you'd need to change `\\mathbf{%2}` in the Lua code to `\\color{red}%2`. Of course, either the `xcolor` or `color` package needs to be loaded in order to get access to the `\color` macro.

[image]

```
\mynum{0}{2.12e-14}, \mynum{2}{-12.34e56}, \mynum{0}{e1234}
```

Comment: thanks, it's a nice example of how to use lua. I ended up doing something along those lines, but directly with the script that generates the latex code from the data. It could be a useful feature to add to siunitx though.

Comment: @baptiste I oppose the idea that this feature is useful. Bold face should never indicate anything but titles or spetial math symbols, such as `\bm{0}` for the zero matrix, `\bm{1}` for the identity matrix etc.

Comment: @yo ' - I've deleted my comments, and written an addendum to the answer to mention that instead of bold-facing, color-highlighting could be done. Will you delete your latter two comments as well, please?

Comment: @yo' i disagree with your point of view; anything that can improve readability is a potentially useful typographic feature. In the context of a table presenting results of numerical simulations, $10^\mathbf{56}$ will never mislead anyone to think that we're taking 10 to the power of a matrix "56", or a vector, or anything else.

Comment: @baptiste (1) Using boldface does not increase readability, it only confuses people. Boldface has a different purpose than emphasizing. In maths, the emphasis is done for instance by commenting on the formula; on slides, colours could be useful. Considering doing "ten to a matrix", note that it is a well-defined operation in maths. Using bold face for emphasizing in a scientific text is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Completely agree with @yo', the font has to provide decent exponent numbers. Bold face is not a solution.

Comment: @MaxNoe - I purposefully provided an addendum to the answer to show that if bold-facing the exponent isn't one's cup of tea, it's straightforward to adapt the code to allow highlighting via colors.

Comment: I know,  I don't  criticise your a answer. In fact , I upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

You can inject `\mathbf` just at the right place in.  I still advise you to *not* use this, as this is doomed to fail if `siunitx` changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_protected:Npn \__siunitx_number_format_final_exponent: {
  \prop_get:NnN \l__siunitx_number_out_prop { exponent }
    \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__siunitx_output_exponent_tl
    {
      \tl_set:Nx \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl
      %{ ^ { \exp_not:V \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl } }
       { ^ { \exp_not:N \mathbf { \exp_not:V \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl } } }
      \tl_put_left:NV \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl \l__siunitx_exponent_base_tl
    }
    {
      \tl_set:Nx  \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl
        {
          \exp_not:V \l__siunitx_output_exponent_tl
          \exp_not:N \mathord
          \exp_not:V  \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl
        }
    }
  \prop_put:NnV \l__siunitx_number_out_prop { exponent-result }
    \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\num{2.12e-14}

\num{12.34e56}

\num{e1234}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: thanks! this code looks scary, I wouldn't want to use it for the reason you state, but thanks for showing how to access that level of control.