# How to expand the result of a siunitx macro to use it as an argument for another marco

Tags: macros, siunitx, expansion

While trying to answer [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/539542/141947), I proposed [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539552/141947), which obviously does not work as expected, otherwise we would not be here.

The solution works for explicit strings but not for strings stemming from a `siunitx` macro such as `\num`, which is the behavior expected by the OP, so if you find a solution, feel free to propose it in the original question.

So my question is, how to force latex to expand the result of `\num{xxx}` before a macro using it as an argument ?

It probably can be solved with `\expandafter` and related functions, but I just managed to mess everything while trying these.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\addbelowarrow}[2]{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\charbefore}{#2-1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\charafter}{#2+1}
    \StrMid{#1}{1}{\charbefore}%
    \tikzmarknode{tempnode}{\StrChar{#1}{#2}}%
    \StrMid{#1}{\charafter}{100}%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[stealth-] (tempnode) --++ (0,-2em);}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item  \addbelowarrow{123456789}{4} % works fine
    \item  \addbelowarrow{\num{123456789}}{4} % does not work
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't, \num is not expandable. But if you only want the number you could read it from the argument and ignore the \num.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do not know how to react to that. Could you explain a bit why ? You mean there is no way to store the string output from `\num` ? I know it may seem a really dumb question to ask, but I just don't understand at the moment.

Comment: `\num` doesn't make strings it is a typesetting command, you would have similar issues if you used `\textbf{12}textit{245}\hspace{2pt}678`  you can't use string operations on such a thing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess this is one of these tex mind-blowing situations (to me, probably not to you). Then you mean that what the original poster (I mean in the linked question) asks is not possible. Can you confirm?

Comment: You could try to "hack" siunitx. Somehow convince it that when ever it typesets a digit to wrap a `\tikzmarknode` around it. Either there is already something that allows you to wrap a macro around digits or you need to know/learn expl3 or cheat.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276457/194703) is an analogous hack. That probably buries the idea.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, yes it seems indeed... I just tried the same thing with a `\pgfmathprintnumber` instead of the `\num`, but I also get errors. Do you know if it's the same process, i.e. typesetting or does the pgf one assemble strings ?

Comment: @BambOo Yes, you cannot store the result of `\pgfmathprintnumber` in a macro AFAIK.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I was reviewing my unanswered questions. If you want to write an answer, let me know. I will otherwise close/write an answer to collect the comments.

Comment: @BambOo feel free to self answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle will do, thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is merely a collection of the above comments (thanks for the kind remarks to Ulrike  Fischer, David Carlisle and Schrödinger's cat**

- `\num` is a typesetting command, it does not assemble strings per se, so there is not expandable output of this function. As an example it makes as much sense to try to expand `\num{1.234}` than  `\textbf{12}textit{245}\hspace{2pt}678` to a string
- `\pgfmathprintnumber` seems to work in the same fashion, so here again, the result is not expandable.